# C# TaskCancellationTokenSource IsCancellationRequested never caught

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, cancellationtokensource

Could anybody help me understand how cancellation task works? I read some simple examples from   [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation) but my implementation does not work as expected.

Below something I try to work with:

```
    private Task _Task { get; set; }

    private CancellationTokenSource _TaskCancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

    private void StartTask()
    {
        _TaskCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _Task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if(_TaskCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Canceling");

                    _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Running");

                await Task.Delay(10000, _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
        }, _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void StopTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stoping task");
        _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("Task stoped");
    }
```

I Invoke StartTask() and after each 10s. console writes "Running" as it should be. But after invoking StopTask() only "Stopping task" and "Task stopped" appears. "Canceling" is never written to console. But VS debugger shows in Task properties that have been canceled and "Running" never appear again.

Comment: … you are not awaiting `_Task` as far as I can see… Unhandled exceptions, including cancellations, will go unnoticed. How and when are you calling `StartTask` and `StopTask`?

Comment: Task.Delay is going to throw a TaskCanceledException before getting to your check.

Comment: Mike you are right.

I changed:
await Task.Delay(10000, _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Token);
To:
await Task.Delay(10000);

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel(); throw some kind of exception in your child thread. (Might be TaskCanceledException)

Try wrapping your task code in a try/catch enclosure, and display your message on your catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Mike's comment below my questions is right.

Task.Delay is creating task with the same cancelation token.

I changed it from:

```
await Task.Delay(3000, _TaskCancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

To:

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
```

and it works exactly as I wanted.